# Allure uuid not the same of *-result.json file

Tags: python, allure

It used to be the same "uuid" and the "uuid-result.json" file but now it doesn't match and I need to be the same. Does someone know how to solve it?

The name of the file and uuid should be the same. It only happens in Python because in Java it works well.

Comment: It is not part of the public contract. For Java integrations, Allure uses test result uuid as a file name, but it is not required. Why do you need it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.